# how to get correct geo reference system for a VMap

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr, georeferencing, c++

I am new to GIS, trying to read the GeoRef System for VMap by using the following code:

```
    OGRSpatialReference *ref = layer->GetSpatialRef();

    if( ref )
    {
        QString georefSystem = ref->GetAttrValue( "GEOGCS" );
    }
```

its reading and returning as NAD83 for the map which is WGS84.
I confirmed the map is WGS84 by opening it in global mapper.

please let me know what I am missing here to get the correct Geo reference system.

My work  environment is C++ in Windows 7.

Thanks,
Prady